# C# SQLite reader in for loop slow

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I am retrieving data from a sqlite database using a data reader.
This is executed in a double for loop. But it's very slow, because now it's executing the sql query multiple times.

Is there a more quick way to do this?
Here is a short version of what I am doing now:

```
for(int i=0;i < horizontal; i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j < vertical; j++)
  {
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);
    cmd.CommandText = query;        
    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(reader);
    con.Close();

    // Perform some actions onto DataTable data
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Opening and closing before the loop doesn't help a lot.
I am trying to query all the rows of the table where the position column is between 4 points, perform some calculations on it and move to the next cell (think of a grid).

Comment: no need to create SQLiteConnection object frequent time in loop. Create it before loop and close con after loop.

Comment: Tried it but not a real solution. The problem is the query that's executed horizontal * vertical times. But i don't know how i can make this less.

Comment: Can you show the SQL query and explain what is the purpose of the nested loop and how does it affect the query?

Comment: The nested loop affects the data that's selected from the database (WHERE x BETWEEN xmin AND xmax AND y BETWEEN ymin AND ymax).

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);
for(int i=0;i < horizontal; i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j < vertical; j++)
  {
    cmd.CommandText = query;    
    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(reader);
    // Perform some actions onto DataTable data
  }
}
con.Close();
```

only change the command text, no need to instance a new one each time. Also, only close it when you are done doing queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same connection you can create SQLiteConnection object and open the connection above iterations, you should also close the connection under iterations. It should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Do you `using Finisar.SQLite;`?

If so, try change to `using System.Data.SQLite;`.
It's very helpful to me, form 6s reduce to 150 ms.